# How to verify if my network is under a man-in-the-middle attack?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, security, git

### What happened?

When I tried to pull from one of my repos, I got the following error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that the RSA host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:JusGXNrzFuQBPkLWthJ5pPjJQckIUe25VS0i1CMoszk.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
RSA host key for ras.mydomain.com has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

### What I tried to do

1. I did some googling, and they recommended to just remove the host and reconnect. I had my suspicions (better safe then sorry) but I went ahead carefully. `ssh-keygen -R  github.com` removed github from `known_hosts`.
2. Okay and now let's test the connection with `ssh -T git@github.com`, this was the answer:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.4)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:+QolW6mvi95EFAGeZpAjL2fOQ2rmB4uESAvNHE9IpFI.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

And it seems like that the fingerprint is different than what is on their [website](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints). I might be overcomplicating this, and I don't have any company secrets in my repos, but at this point, I am curious if there is something I am missing, or if there is really something off with my network.

### My conclusion

While finishing up this question it occurred to me to check out what happens if I use my cellular device to authenticate, and sure enough, running `ssh -T git@github.com` gave a different result.

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.121.3)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
```

This time, I got the same fingerprint that is on the website, so to me it seems like this might indeed be a man in the middle attack. I have a home LAN with a NAS and some PCs. **How should I proceed, how can I locate the man in the middle? Can there be any other explanation behind this?**

**Edit:**

I found out what was the problem, but I still don't understand why it is happening. As I mentioned, I have a NAS that i use to back up my data from my laptop. I use SFTP to do this, and I am forwarding from port 22 on my router to the NAS. This is what caused this error, so I changed the port I use for backup.

Comment: One explanation would be that some legitimate device (or software) is trying to act as a middleman to analyze the traffic. I haven't heard about this being done with SSH connections though.

Comment: The site at https://140.82.121.4 is indeed Github, but there is a problem with their certificate. I also had a warning message when connecting and had to tell my browser to accept it (temporarily).

Comment: Github recently changed certificates so you are probably not dealing with anything nefarious. https://github.community/t/change-of-servers-certificates/168866/2

Comment: Thanks! Could it have been pihole that was meddling in the traffic?

Comment: No. Pihole could only resolve the domain name to a different IP, but you're getting the same one in both attempts, so it's working fine.